# Rails 3 - Ajax and controller refactor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails and I'd like to know if I could refactor the following code.

Basically I want to vote_down ou vote_up for a question in ajax.

Controller :

```
def vote_up
@question = get_question params[:id]
if current_user != @question.user
  render :json => @question.vote(current_user, 'up').to_json
 end
end

def vote_down
@question = get_question params[:id]
if current_user != @question.user
  render :json => @question.vote(current_user, 'down').to_json
 end
end
```

Model :

```
def vote(user, vote)
if user.voted?(self)
  'Question already voted'
else
  I18n.t('question.voted') if user.send("#{vote}_vote", self)
 end
end
```

View :

```
<script>
 $('#question_vote_up').live('ajax:success', function(evt, data,    status, xhr) {
 $('#question_vote_up').remove()
 $('#question_vote_down').remove()
 alert(xhr.responseText)
 })

 $('#question_vote_down').live('ajax:success', function(evt, data,      status, xhr) {
 $('#question_vote_up').remove()
 $('#question_vote_down').remove()
 alert(xhr.responseText)
 })
 </script>

 <% if current_user != @question.user %>
 <%= link_to t('question.vote_up'), { :action => "vote_up" }, :id => "question_vote_up", :remote => true %>
 <%= link_to t('question.vote_down'), { :action => "vote_down" }, :id => "question_vote_down", :remote => true %>
 <% end %>
```

I can't figure out how don't repeat myself and if there is a cleaner way to

```
if current_user != @question.user
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following might work (not tested, just make sure not to double render):

```
def getQuestion(direction)
  @question = get_question params[:id]
  if current_user != @question.user
      render :json => @question.vote(current_user, direction).to_json
  else
      render :nothing => true
  end
end

def vote_up
   getQuestion "up"
end

def vote_down
   getQuestion "down"       
end
```

Comment: This is a nice approach but in case of current_user == @question.user render nothing raise a "template missing error".

Comment: well you could return an empty object as well, as long as you can handle that condition. I've made an edit to incorporate that.